# If I want to check my CentOS version which release file is most accurate?

Tags: linux, centos, rhel

I'm aware that there's a couple of methods to check your CentOS release version but if I want to check using the release files I see there's two options.

cat /etc/centos-release
or
cat /etc/redhat-release

is there any reason to choose one over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No difference at all.

`/etc/redhat-release` is a symbolic link to `/etc/centos-release`

From the terminal, execute the following and note the output:

```
$ ls -l /etc/redhat-release
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 14 Dec 10  2019 /etc/redhat-release -> centos-release
```